# Java Soap request - reading soap response

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to get specific values from response I get from webservice. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it. I used code found on stackoverflow for creating soap request and writing out response content into stdout:

```
private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
}
```

It all works well but I dont need whole response content:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bin="http://localhost/WebService/bindings" xmlns:typ="http://localhost/WebService/types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bin:doActionResponse>
         <bin:out>
            <typ:result>
               <typ:code>?</typ:code>
               <typ:description>?</typ:description>
            </typ:result>
         </bin:out>
      </bin:doActionResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I just need value of code and description from this response. How can I do this?

Comment: have a look at XPATH if you are trying to just get a single element from a soap message http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java

Comment: I believe there is a way to do something like: `soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagName()` but I keep getting some strange values while trying to do like this.

Answer (score 18):

Here is the whole working example for some other xml example;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SOAPException {

    String xmlInput = "  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:web=\"http://litwinconsulting.com/webservices/\">\n"
            + "   <soapenv:Header/>\n"
            + "   <soapenv:Body>\n"
            + "   <web:RES>\n"
            + "      <web:RETURNCODE>100 </web:RETURNCODE> \n"
            + "   </web:RES>\n"
            + "      <web:GetWeather>\n"
            + "         <!--Optional:-->\n"
            + "         <web:City>%CITY%</web:City>\n"
            + "      </web:GetWeather>\n"
            + "   </soapenv:Body>\n"
            + "  </soapenv:Envelope>";

    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(
            new MimeHeaders(),
            new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlInput.getBytes(Charset
                    .forName("UTF-8"))));

    SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

    NodeList returnList = body.getElementsByTagName("web:RES");

    boolean isSuccess = false;
    for (int k = 0; k < returnList.getLength(); k++) {
        NodeList innerResultList = returnList.item(k).getChildNodes();
        for (int l = 0; l < innerResultList.getLength(); l++) {
            if (innerResultList.item(l).getNodeName()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("web:RETURNCODE")) {
                isSuccess = Integer.valueOf(innerResultList.item(l)
                        .getTextContent().trim()) == 100 ? true : false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isSuccess) {
        NodeList list = body.getElementsByTagName("web:GetWeather");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            NodeList innerList = list.item(i).getChildNodes();

            for (int j = 0; j < innerList.getLength(); j++) {
                System.out.println(innerList.item(j).getNodeName());
                System.out.println(innerList.item(j).getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and imports if you needed ;

- java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
- java.io.IOException;
- java.nio.charset.Charset;
- javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
- javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
- javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
- javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
- javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
- org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

Comment: This method works, but it is getting very lengthy, is there a way I can do this by using xPath ? @NoBrainer